# Displaying images based on dynamic array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a server generated Array, which can return one up to six array items. These array items are "categories," based on category, they will display a different image (There are eight custom images that can be selected from per category, but this happens behind the scenes). So only one image is being established per category. However, there can also be a "custom" image uploaded, which takes priority if present. So in reality, the server will return one or two images, per category. On top of that, a user can fall into multiple categories, so I need to add a priority level based on category so one overrides the other, I'm trying to figure out how to handle this efficiently and struggling. Particularly in the priority area; should I add another namespace to the array to specify priority level and designate based on lowest value? What is the most efficient way to compare array values and return results?

Edit: By efficient, I mean, scalable and maintainable, not necessarily performant.

```js
console.clear();
// banner element
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
// 3s timout
window.setTimeout(function() {
  // add class (class handles fade transition) 
  banner.classList.add('fade-in');
}, 3000);

// Array generated from "Architecture Priorities" field, not all will display, but more than one can.
var arc = [
    'Collaboration',
    'Data Center',/*
    'Enterprise Networks',
    'Security',
    'Services',*/
    'Cross Architecture'
  ],
  
  // manual array and image defaults (will need to utilize zval() for "path")
  img = [{
    name: 'Collaboration',
    path: '//placehold.it/1200x400/fa4/fff', // value returned from server based on user input.
    customPath: '' // value returned from server based on user input
  }, {
    name: 'Data Center',
    path: '//placehold.it/1200x400/4af/fff',
    customPath: ''
  }, {
    name: 'Enterprise Networks',
    path: '//placehold.it/1200x400/af4/fff',
    customPath: ''
  }, {
    name: 'Security',
    path: '//placehold.it/1200x400/4fa/fff',
    customPath: ''
  }, {
    name: 'Services',
    path: '//placehold.it/1200x400/f4a/fff',
    customPath: ''
  }, {
    name: 'Cross Architecture',
    path: '//placehold.it/1200x400/a4f/fff',
    customPath: '//placehold.it/1200x400/222/fff?text=custom'
  }];

for (var prop in img) {
  if (img.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arc.length; i++) {
      if(img[prop].name === arc[i]){
        if (img[prop].customPath !== '') {
         banner.setAttribute('src', img[prop].customPath);
        } else {
          banner.setAttribute('src', img[prop].path);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.banner-wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  background: transparent url('//placehold.it/1200x400/222/fff') no-repeat center center / cover;
}

img {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

img.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-wrapper">
  <img src="//placehold.it/1200x400/fff/222" width="1200" height="400" id="banner">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try that. 
I add priority key in your img collection then i take img with the highest priority.

```
var arc = [
  "Collaboration",
  "Data Center" /*
    'Enterprise Networks',
    'Security',
    'Services',*/,
  "Cross Architecture"
];
var imgs = [
  {
    name: "Collaboration",
    path: "//placehold.it/1200x400/fa4/fff", // value returned from server based on user input.
    customPath: "", // value returned from server based on user input,
    priority: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Data Center",
    path: "//placehold.it/1200x400/4af/fff",
    customPath: "",
    priority: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Enterprise Networks",
    path: "//placehold.it/1200x400/af4/fff",
    customPath: "",
    priority: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Security",
    path: "//placehold.it/1200x400/4fa/fff",
    customPath: "",
    priority: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Services",
    path: "//placehold.it/1200x400/f4a/fff",
    customPath: "",
    priority: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Cross Architecture",
    path: "//placehold.it/1200x400/a4f/fff",
    customPath: "//placehold.it/1200x400/222/fff?text=custom",
    priority: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Collaboration",
    path: "//placehold.it/1200x400/fa4/fff", // value returned from server based on user input.
    customPath: "", // value returned from server based on user input,
    priority: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Data Center",
    path: "//placehold.it/1200x400/4af/fff",
    customPath: "",
    priority: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Enterprise Networks",
    path: "//placehold.it/1200x400/af4/fff",
    customPath: "",
    priority: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Security",
    path: "//placehold.it/1200x400/4fa/fff",
    customPath: "",
    priority: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Services",
    path: "//placehold.it/1200x400/f4a/fff",
    customPath: "",
    priority: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Cross Architecture",
    path: "//placehold.it/1200x400/a4f/fff",
    customPath: "//placehold.it/1200x400/222/fff?text=custom",
    priority: 1
  }
];
var priotiziredImgs = {};
imgs.forEach(img => {
  if (arc.indexOf(img.name) > -1) {
    let name = img.name;
    if (priotiziredImgs[name]) {
      priotiziredImgs[name] =
        img.priority > priotiziredImgs[name].priority
          ? img
          : priotiziredImgs[name];
    } else {
      priotiziredImgs[name] = img;
    }
  }
});
```

With this you get images with the highest priority for a given category. And then you can
do a loop again to append them to the dom.

```
Object.keys(priotiziredImgs).forEach(name => {
  let src = priotiziredImgs[name].customPath.length
    ? priotiziredImgs[name].customPath
    : priotiziredImgs[name].path;
  banner.setAttribute("src", src);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking, just seemed cumbersome to me.